# how do I access (e.g., cout) the current value of iterators in multi-dimensional STL vectors (C++)

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm still very much a neophyte in using STL. The following code fragment populates a 3D vector (S) and compiles (g++) fine.

```
const int maxBonds = 6;
vector< vector< vector<int> > > S;
S.resize(maxBonds);
populate(S); // function that returns S with various layers filled with int data in rows and columns.
for (vector<vector<vector<int> > >::iterator Slayer = S.begin(); Slayer != S.end(); Slayer++) {
    cout << "Layer contains " << Slayer->size() << " rows" << endl;
    for (vector<vector<int> >::iterator Srow = Slayer->begin(); Srow != Slayer->end(); Srow++) {
        for (vector<int>::iterator Scol = Srow->begin(); Scol != Srow->end(); Scol++) {
            cout << *Scol;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

This runs fine:

```
Layer contains 0 rows

Layer contains 5 rows
000
200
020
220
002

Layer contains 12 rows
100
010
210
... // etc.
```

However, I'd like to print out the value of the outer iterators (Slayer, Srow) during iteration. How do I properly dereference the current value of Slayer, i.e.

```
 cout << "Layer # " << Slayer->??? << " contains " << Slayer->size() << " rows" << endl;
```

Comment: is not Slayer an iterator? Does not *Slayer work simply?

Comment: @Umut - works, but it would be a vector and you cannot print a vector just like that.

Comment: @Kiril, indeed, that is a vector<vector<int> >

Comment: @Rolf, you might formulate the problem in a better way for future reference perhaps, formulating the 3d thing with a pointer to vector<vector<int> > decreases the level of nests, sth like that...

Comment: @Umut: trying to do cout << *Slayer does not work, the << operator cannot be used here.

Comment: @Rolf, have to use std::vector?? you can use some matrix classes, boost for instance, like pages in a book, pointers point to these pages and then you iterate on them, a better structure, hth...

Comment: @Rolf, see the answer from Kiril, and reformulate the problem ;)

Comment: @Rolf - you **can** use `operator<<`, if you overload it, as I already said in my answer.

Comment: @Umut, thanks, they aren't really arrays (not rectangular), and need to grow and shrink dynamically, so std::vector seemed to fit the bill. But @Kiril, if I pass Slayer to `void Print3dIntVector( const vector<vector<int> >& v )`, how does this allow access by cout to the current value as it iterates? Don't I run into the same problem, i.e., can't use cout with a vector (Clearly revealing my ignorance here ...)?

Comment: @Rolf, did you look at the answers there is one that is proposing to use a counter, if that is the ultimate goal?

Comment: @Umut, yes thanks, just saw it. Cheers, Rolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is the current vector "index", i think that the standard way to do this is to increment another value.

```
unsigned int countSlayer = 0;

for (vector<vector<vector<int> > >::iterator Slayer = S.begin(); Slayer != S.end(); Slayer++, ++countSlayer) {

    cout << "Layer # " << countSlayer << " contains " << Slayer->size() << " rows" << endl;

    for (vector<vector<int> >::iterator Srow = Slayer->begin(); Srow != Slayer->end(); Srow++) {
        for (vector<int>::iterator Scol = Srow->begin(); Scol != Srow->end(); Scol++) {
            cout << *Scol;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

You can also try to subtract begin() from the iterator but it doesn't work well with all iterators types (I lack time for making some tests).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly.

The way I'd do it - define an function with a loop to do this for you.

---

Something like:

```
void Print2dIntVector( const vector<vector<int> >& v )
{
    // ..
}
void Print3dIntVector( const vector< vector< vector<int> > >& v )
{
    // ..
}
```

Advice - use `typedef`, instead of writing all these long, nested vectors.

**EDIT**: Of cource, you can always overload `operator<<` for these types (vectors)

Answer (score 0):

So `*Scol` gets you the int within the last vector, `*Srow` would get you the vector of the row, `*Slayer` would get you the vector of the layers containing the vector of rows.